# How to subtract a time from date time format in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a particular date and time with me in shell. Now I need to subtract 7 hours from that particular date and time.
eg.
2018-03-20 21:00:00 -> 2018-03-20 14:00:00
2018-03-20 06:00:00 -> 2018-03-19 23:00:00

I have both date and time in different strings as well.

How to write this in shell (v4.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementations of `date` understand time arithmetics like "-7 hours":

```
#!/bin/bash

format='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Test () {
    date=$1
    time=$2
    expect=$3

    d=$(date "$format %Z" -d "$date $time")
    plus7=$(date "$format" -d "$d -7 hours")
    if [[ $plus7 == $expect ]] ; then
        echo ok
    else
        echo $plus7
    fi
}

Test 2018-03-20 21:00:00 '2018-03-20 14:00:00'
Test 2018-03-20 06:00:00 '2018-03-19 23:00:00'
```

Tested with `date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`.

Comment: the trick is adding the timezone in the format before date/time operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the POSIX arithmetic operator in conjunction with `date -d@` to subtract 7 hours (7 * 3600 seconds) from any given date, e.g.

```
$ date -d@$(($(date -d"2018-03-20 21:00:00" +%s) - 7 * 3600))
Tue Mar 20 14:00:00 CDT 2018
```